# Grid system doesn't work in Semantic UI (can't align properly)

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a 4 column grid in Semantic UI (its default is 16 columns), so each column has a width of 4. However, I feel completely lost because the grid doesn't work properly! Here's how it looks like on my computer (tested both with Firefox and Chromium, same result):

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
    <div class="four wide column"></div>
</div>
```

[Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtKiz.png)

Using the same code it displays properly on JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fnL73zL0/

**Working Example**:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui grid">
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
  <div class="four wide column"></div>
</div>
```

What's wrong? I remember that I had similar problem with Bootstrap. The problem is really terrible because without a working grid I can't make any serious website.

Comment: show me your <head> tag @wenn

Comment: Somehow I got it to work by redownloading the Semantic UI CSS file, if it happens again I will comment here.

Comment: No issues! :) @wenn